# Que pasa si abro un archivo y no lo cierro?

Tags: c, archivo, fopen

Soy nuevo programando en ansi C. Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a manipular archivos.

Mi duda es si abro un archivo utilizando la funcion fopen, y termino el programa sin utilizar fclose, el archivo se puede danar o queda algun proceso pendiente en la PC o simplemente no pasa nada?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es probable que el resultado de no cerrarlo sea dependiente de plataforma, pero en el peor de los casos puede que termines con un archivo vacío. Te recomiendo poner un pequeño ejemplo en la pregunta, para que la gente entienda mejor el problema que expones :), saludos!

Comment: Lo más seguro es que no pase nada. Pero esto es como sacar los pendrive, discos duros externos, etc. con seguridad. Es áltamente recomendado. Por eso, siempre usa fclose() cuando el tratamiento del fichero haya terminado. Es, además, de buenas prácticas del programador. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El resultado es dependiente del Sistema Operativo.

Cuando tu adquieres un recurso (un fichero, un socket, ...) el sistema te reserva dicho recurso ofreciéndote un acceso exclusivo al mismo. Nadie más podrá acceder a dicho recurso mientras lo tengas reservado.

Si el acceso requerido es de lectura únicamente, el sistema puede ofrecer un acceso compartido al recurso siempre y cuando todos los accesos sean de lectura.

Si tu adquieres un recurso pero no lo liberas, el sistema mantiene la reserva del mismo, por lo que impides que otra aplicación pueda acceder al mismo.

Lo que normalmente sucede (al menos en Sistemas Operativos modernos) es que al cerrar tu aplicación los recursos asociados a dicha aplicación se liberan automáticamente... pero no tiene por qué ser necesariamente así. Si resulta que los recursos no se liberan se quedarán bloqueados indefinidamente (pues tu aplicación ya no será capaz de liberarlos al perder los identificadores de los mismos) y la única solución será reiniciar el equipo.

Hay que tener especial cuidado con los recursos remotos, ya que entonces es bastante probable que el Sistema Operativo remoto no tenga constancia de que tu aplicación se haya cerrado, con lo que la posibilidad de que los recursos queden bloqueados aumenta significativamente.